# Find the first div from class

Tags: jquery

Trying to find if a div is the first shown in a class.
At the moment, first div is not selected.

html:

```
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix"></div> <!--need this one-->
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix"></div>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix"></div>
```

jquery:

```
if ($('div[class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix"]').is(':first')) {
// do something with first div
} else {
//edit others
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first item of the jquery colelction use .first()

`$('div.servline_vhc.servline_vhc_inspection.clearfix').first()`

see: https://api.jquery.com/first/

#### Working example:

```js
var $div = $('div.servline_vhc.servline_vhc_inspection.clearfix').first();
$div.text("I'm first");
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">X</div>
<!--need this one-->
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">X</div>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">X</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector match all of three.

```js
$('div[class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix"]').append(' - match');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">1</div>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">2</div>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">3</div>
```

If you want to select only first only element, either append [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector into your query or use [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) method. Also to query by css classes you can simply write a query as `element.class1.class2`:

```js
$('div.servline_vhc.servline_vhc_inspection.clearfix:first').append(' :first');
$('div.servline_vhc.servline_vhc_inspection.clearfix').first().append(' .first()');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">1</div>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">2</div>
<div class="servline_vhc servline_vhc_inspection clearfix">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".servline_vhc:first")){
}
```

Comment: Hi Ruwaid Bin Yousuf - your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.